# Closing FancyBox from submit on form (iframe)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit, fancybox-2

I'm trying to close a fancy box iframe on a submit, but can't really get i to work

The no button works fine, it's a standard  but the submit button won't close the window.

Here is the code..

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="unrelease.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeID" value="<?php echo $EmployeeID;?>"/>
    <p class="alert alert-error">Er du sikker på at du vil slette medarbejderen?</p>
    <div class="form-actions">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick=”parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();”>Yes</button>
     <a class="btn" href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">No</a>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Is there anybody that can help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: just a guess but the quotes around your onclick look strange - have you tried replacing them with standard quotes?

Comment: You have got good eyes! It solved the problem, thanks a bunch!

Comment: no probs, I've posted it as a proper answer, accept it if you wish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dodgy quotes - you need to replace

```
onclick=”parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();”
```

with

```
onclick="parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();"
```

Comment: *dodgy* hehe, love it. First time I see that term. I'm a "curly" quotes kinda guy ;-)